# Make a Java class have higher compile priority than one inside a library in IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, extends

We have some portion of functionality packed in an external library and it is attached to our project. That library can't be changed in any way. Amongst others there are two classes lying inside it: `com.myorg.Grandpa` and `com.myorg.Dad` that extends `com.myorg.Grandpa`. Also there are `com.myorg.Grandson` extending `com.myorg.Dad` and a few other classes outside of the library extending `com.myorg.Grandpa`.

I decompile `com.myorg.Grandpa` class and add a new method `new_method()` to it.
Then I try to use `new_method()` in `com.myorg.Grandson` but IDEA won't let me do it cause Grandson extends Dad which extends library's Grandpa which doesn't contain `new_method()`.
I tried to delete Grandpa from library and surprisingly IDEA didn't say a word and successfully compiled a project despite of the fact that in the boundaries of a library Dad extends non existing class.

The question is how to force Dad to extend a new Grandpa without deleting the one inside a library?

Comment: OT: Your model seems a little bit strange. Dad 'is-a' Grandpa and then Grandson 'is-a' Dad. Is this really your intention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could

- Add an abstract class between `Dad` and `GrandSon`: Extend `Dad`, and add your method in the sub class. Then derive `GrandSon` from that sub class.
- Put an instance of `Dad` in a new class, and let your IDE create delegate methods to the aggregated `Dad` instance. Again add your new method to the new class.

There is another possibility:

- If you have to modify classes *in place*, use `aspectj` to weave in code: aspectj changes the byte-code (it does not need source code) at run-time. This way you can add methods or fields.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that you are duplicating classes with full package signature, so you will get the one that the classloader loads first. I know that in Websphere you can tweak classloader priorities, but couldn't say in your case.

Anyway, why not just do it without decompiling? You are causing yourself hard coupling to an external library and bad practices (maybe copyright issues) by decompiling/customizing. Besides, if the library gets updated, you will run into trouble having to reconstruct your customized classes.

Options:

Create your own implementation, for instance:

1. Create an Interface that replicates all methods in Grandpa plus the one you need.
2. Extend Grandpa class and implement the added method from your interface, all other methods will be left intact.
3. Extend all other extending classes from your own class hierarchie.
4. Instead of using the libraries common class, use your Interface as naming

This way you are kind of creating your own interface to the library, if it changes, you know where to make changes.

You could even do it without the interface, it's kind of wrapping the functionality, it would depend on what you need to achieve.

Anyway, I would try to solve it by own code and not by messing up with the library, it is just not worth it to do such tricks, if a new Programmer takes the project, they will need a lot of time to find out why and how it behaves.

Now, there might be variations in how to structure the class hierarchie, but it would depend on the specific implementation you need, so you would have to post more detailed data on what the library is and what you're trying to add to it if you expect some more specific answer...

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It has to appear first to the class loader.

IDEA should load your class first if is in your project. You may also try to create a separate library for your class and include it in your project.

See also: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html